# How to save the material in library

Tags: materials

I want to save material in library. i have install Material library vx addon but i want to add other material to that addon how can in add. Plz explain brief. Or is there other addon present that can save my material in library[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add a material to your library, first you have to save your file with the material you want to add to the library.

Next, click add material in the menu as pictured below, and it will be added to the library and available for future use.

[image]

The other alternative is to add a new material to the appropriate .blend file in the addon folder. Remember to save it, or it will be lost of course.

There should be a .blend for each material library the add-on provides as shown below.

[image]

Comment: If i have take a new file add all the material that i need and save that file and after adding the material can i delete that file. can u send me the link of ur material library vx look i have older version install. And is the preview of that material avilable

Comment: My version was with the 2.78RC release. [This](https://sites.google.com/site/aleonserra/home/scripts/matlib-vx-5-6) is the documentation link from inside Blender, it has the link at the bottom of the page. Yes, you can preview your materials just like any other, and deleting the file you made one in is fine, I did that myself.